# MySQL - Query with grouped conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

Hi,

I have table with row like the above picture and i would like to sum QTY of all row but i need to exclude row where AISLE = POS and QTY < 0 on the same row.

I made some try to get what i want but i can't find solution :

```
SELECT
  ROUND(SUM(QTY),
  2) AS INVENTORY
FROM
  INV_QTY_LOCATION
WHERE
  PRODUCT = 143459 AND AISLE != 'PHY' AND AISLE != 'RET' AND case when AISLE = 'POS' AND QTY > 0
```

Another try

```
SELECT
  ROUND(SUM(QTY),
  2) AS INVENTORY
FROM
  INV_QTY_LOCATION
WHERE
  PRODUCT = 143459 AND AISLE != 'PHY' AND AISLE != 'RET' AND (AISLE = 'POS' AND QTY > 0)
```

In this particular case the result should be 161.

**Solution**

```
SELECT
  ROUND(
    SUM(
      CASE WHEN(AISLE = 'POS' AND QTY > 0) OR AISLE != 'POS' THEN QTY ELSE 0
    END
  ),
  2
) AS INVENTORY
FROM
  INV_QTY_LOCATION
WHERE
  PRODUCT = 143459 AND AISLE != 'PHY' AND AISLE != 'RET'
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to note that `NOT IN` would be helpful for this query:

```
WHERE PRODUCT = 143459 AND
      AISLE NOT IN ('PHY', 'RET') AND
      (AISLE <> 'POS' OR QTY > 0)
```

Note:  This assumes that `AISLE` is never `NULL`.

Or, alternatively:

```
WHERE PRODUCT = 143459 AND
      AISLE NOT IN ('PHY', 'RET') AND
      NOT (AISLE = 'POS' AND QTY > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

your second statement was almost correct, but since you are trying to "exclude AISLE = POS", then it should be `AISLE <> 'POS'`:

```
SELECT
  ROUND(SUM(QTY),
  2) AS INVENTORY
FROM
  INV_QTY_LOCATION
WHERE
  PRODUCT = 143459 AND AISLE != 'PHY' AND AISLE != 'RET' AND (AISLE <> 'POS' OR QTY > 0)
```

Comment: This is not good since if row with AISLE = POS is > 0 i need to include this row. With this query row with AISLE = POS is always exlude.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I have updated my answer to be inclusive with `AND (AISLE <> 'POS' OR QTY > 0)`. But, you should check out [**@Gordon Linoff**'s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36754667/mysql-query-with-grouped-conditions/36754793#36755078) as I think it's better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
AND (AISLE <> 'POS' OR QTY >= 0)
```